# Upgrade Errors While Opening Solution in a newer version of Visual Studio - Step By Step Fix

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework

When an older solution file is opened from a Visual Studio version higher than the one it was written on there are almost always errors.  The logical approach might be to start with the updates to extensions but that also causes issues along the way.

Is there a specific set of instructions regarding the better method to use while upgrading an old project to a newer version of Visual Studio?

Example:
There are three updates pending:

```
1) Live Share
2) ML.NET Model Builder 2019
3) SQL Server Integration Services
```

There are 559 errors (first four as examples):

```
Optimization does not exist
BundleCollection could not be found
Mvc does not exist in the namespace
GlobalFilterCollection could not be found
```

Should the Updates be the first place to start?
Is there a better methodology for this upgrade process?

Answer (score 1):

Changes to the project model from one version of Visual Studio to the next may require that projects and solutions be upgraded so that they can run on the newer version. The Visual Studio SDK provides interfaces that can be used to implement upgrade support in your own projects.

To support an upgrade, your project system implementation must define and implement an upgrade strategy. In determining your strategy, you can choose to support side-by-side (SxS) backup, copy backup, or both.

You can review this document for workarounds for solutions created in earlier versions of Visual Studio to open in newer versions.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/internals/upgrading-projects?view=vs-2022#upgrading-custom-projects